# How to add custom blocks in drupal?

Tags: drupal-6

I have a simple module which will return a form , but now i have added this to a menu like
admin/settings/
But i want this form in another page ,so i added a hook_block() , my module showed up in the blocks page and i added it to be seen by all in all pages in content area but i dont get that form ? where did i go wrong ? I am new to drupal any help plz

```
function emp_form_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
     switch ($op) {
          case 'list':
          $blocks[0]['info'] = t('New Block');
          $blocks[0]['cache'] = BLOCK_NO_CACHE;
          return $blocks;
     }
}
```

i am using drupal 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also implement the `view` op, like this:

```
case 'view':
  return array(
    'subject' => t('My awesome form'),
    'content' => drupal_get_form('my_awesome_form'),
  );
  break;
```

Comment: ok i added that drupal_get_form('my module') but i got only the subject line but not the form, if i add a text as content i get it , but i am not able to display the form. 
I have added this hook_block() in the same module where i have the form . Should i have seperate modules ?

Comment: i found another way to display form . . . using node_load